# CKEditor no options displayed for styles

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In CKEditor when I open Font Size, Font Family, Format, text background color, text color and close these by click on their open button or any other editor button it removes options for these controls

how can I fix this

[image: ERROR]

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editLT', {
                                                        language: 'en',
                                                        toolbar:[['Source','-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo',
                                                                  'Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor','BGColor'],
                                                                  ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript','-','RemoveFormat','-',
                                                                   'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote',
                                                                   //'-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock',
                                                                   '-', 'Link','Unlink','-', 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar']]
                                                       ,uiColor: '#cfd1cf'
                                                       ,height:300
                                                       ,image_previewText:' '
                                                    });
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Can you share the initialisation code for Ckeditor which you have used?

Comment: code added, no errors on console, it is initialized in Jquery Dialog (extended)

Comment: Please consider this article: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/15-06-02-06-09/full/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html. I think you might use older version of documentation. Please consider it, because your code looks different.

Comment: Thanks zmii But this works fine apart from only problem I am asking in this thread

Comment: Check this article – https://gist.github.com/Reinmar/b9df3f30a05786511a42

Comment: Thanks Reinmar, but this has not solved my problem